# Can mathematical induction be applied on any total order set?

Tags: induction, order-theory

I found a statement said that the proposition "**Mathematical induction can be applied on any total order set**" is **False**.

(The place I found the statement might not be believable.)

This means that there is a counterexample where cannot the math induction be applied.
I didn't find out much information about the relation of Mathematical induction and total-ordered set. So I guess somewhere I thought wrong.

I have no robust concept about them though, however **I thought that any total-ordered set can be applied math induction**, stated with my naive intuition below:

Because Mathematical induction is based on well-ordering principle, which is applied on $\mathbb{Z^+}$, I'd consider that **any total-ordered set is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z^+}$**. By applying a topological sort on the total-ordered set, we can get a chain. The chain is actually the longest path of the total ordered set, so it preserves the order property. The isomorphism $f$ can be defined by: For all elements $x$ in the total-ordered set, $f(x)=$ " $x$'s order number in the chain".

Hence, I "**guess**" that math induction can be applied on the total-ordered set, 
based on the assumption that "**If any set is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z^+}$, and that isomorphism preserves the order information, then math induction can be applied on it**", which I cannot tell is correct or not.

Thanks for any hint and correction!

Comment: "total ordering" and "well-ordering" are not at all the same.

Comment: Try the real numbers. They are totally ordered. What is the "next real number" after $1$?

Comment: This will work only with ordered group that is countable

Comment: @Shaq Yeah, the rational numbers would like to have a word with you. (Technically it's possible, but it's rare to see it in action. Most often it's something like induction on the denominator instead of on the actual rational number.)

Comment: You can take the rational and do it great with them. It might look hard at a glance, just like at the beginning it is hard to believe the rational are countable. After you realize they are, you can put them on chain and apply the induction. I am not saying its easy cause the relation between $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ is not good, but by concept, the induction will be a good proof

Comment: @Shaq This is unrelated to groups (which mean something specific in math), and also does not in any way require the set to be countable.

Comment: @Shaq "To put them ( the rationals) in chain" still is **not** well-ordering them. We "can put them" in chain (i.e., in a sequence) because we know they're countable, but we've no idea what a well order of them is and that's what we need to apply induction in a reasonable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very general form of induction is *well-founded induction*. Suppose $\le$ well-founds $S$. Since any non-empty subset of $S$ has a $\lt$-minimal element, contrapositively $$(\forall x\in S(x\lt y\to\phi(x))\to\phi(y))\to\forall y\in S(\phi(y)).$$

One can't generalise this to total ordering, which doesn't guarantee an analogous property of $S$'s non-empty subsets.

However, one can sometimes induct without knowing how to well-found a set. For example, [real induction](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/realinduction.pdf) relies on the fact that subsets of $\Bbb R$ have infima and suprema.

Comment: "Real induction" is essentially just that a real interval is a connected space in the order topology ( because $\Bbb R$ is order-dense in itself and  any bounded non-empty subset has a $\sup$ and $\inf.$ E.g. if  $C$ is an open cover of $[0,1]$ let $x\in A$ iff $x\in [0,1]$ and $[0,x]$ can be covered by  a finite subset of $C.$ We show that $A$ is open-and-closed in the connected space $[0,1],$ and since $A$ is not empty (because $0\in A$), therefore $A=[0,1].$...............+1